# gradle catalog does not work correctly with spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a `libs.version.toml` file as

```
[versions]
boot-version = '3.1.4'
cloud-version = '2022.0.4'
openapi-version = '2.2.0'

[libraries]
spring-boot-bom = { module = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies", version.ref = "boot-version" }
spring-boot-actuator = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator' }
spring-boot-data-jpa = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' }
spring-boot-data-redis = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis' }
spring-boot-security = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' }
spring-boot-oauth2-resource-server = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server' }
spring-boot-test = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' }
spring-boot-validation = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation' }
spring-boot-web = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' }
spring-boot-web-services = { module = 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services' }

spring-cloud-bom = { module = 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies', version.ref = 'cloud-version' }
spring-cloud-bootstrap = { module = 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap' }
spring-cloud-config = { module = 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config' }
spring-cloud-eureka-client = { module = 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client' }
spring-cloud-openfeign = { module = 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign' }

spring-kafka = { module = 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka' }

spring-session-data-redis = { module = "org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis", version = "3.1.2" }

h2 = { module = 'com.h2database:h2' }
poi-ooxml = { module = 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml', version = '5.2.4' }

[bundles]
microservice = ['openapi', 'spring-boot-actuator', 'spring-boot-data-jpa', 'spring-boot-validation', 'spring-boot-web',
    'spring-cloud-config', 'spring-cloud-eureka-client', 'spring-cloud-bootstrap', 'oracle']

[plugins]
spring-boot-plugin = { id = 'org.springframework.boot', version.ref = 'boot-version' }
spring-dependency-management-plugin = { id = 'io.spring.dependency-management', version = '1.1.3' }
```

and I publish it to our company nexus with maven-publish plugin,

Then I have a spring boot microservice, with following build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    alias(libs.plugins.spring.boot.plugin)
    alias(libs.plugins.spring.dependency.management.plugin)
}

group = 'my.project.name'
version = '6.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

dependencies {
    implementation platform(libs.spring.cloud.bom)
    implementation libs.bundles.microservice

    compileOnly libs.lombok
    testCompileOnly libs.lombok
    annotationProcessor libs.lombok
    testAnnotationProcessor libs.lombok

    testImplementation libs.spring.boot.test
    testRuntimeOnly libs.h2
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs = ["-Xss8m"]
}
```

when I create Spring boot fat jar many of dependencies are missing, but when I add them by name they are not missing. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the BOM and the TOML do not include the dependencies, they merely provide versioning advice to the project.

Hence, the dependencies are not included in the project if they are not added by name, as you observed.

See more at the Gradle docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Comment: There is no example anywhere for spring boot BOM in libs.versions.toml. From what I can tell it should not even be included in the libs.versions.toml. `implementation(platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))` As for `spring-cloud-dependencies` I'm at a loss

Comment: Since you're pulling the package and ver from the plugin, there's no need.  Just put the plugin in the TOML and use that since they always ccorrelate.  The version of the BOM is locked by the plugin and the plugin is versioned by the TOML.  Nothing else is needed.